# What's up with the apex-component tag?

Tags: discussion

I was recently posting a question regarding Visualforce components, and was surprised to see that we have an [apex-component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apex-component) tag.

Should we change that to just [component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/component) or [visualforce-component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualforce-component)?  Would we eventually have a need for [dynamic-component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-component)?

Answer (score 1):

Good catch - I just made [apex-component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apex-component) a synonym for [visualforce-component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualforce-component) and merged the two, effectively moving them all over to the latter.

We'll burn the [dynamic-component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-component) bridge when we come to it ;-)